# how to multi tenant sso implementation in wos2 identity server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

how to deploy multi tenant SSO in WSO2-IS? for example,
we have an app1 with own user credential and then a tenant is exit , another app as app2 with own user credential that contains second tenant, i am user from tenant1 and logged in app1 and get a saml2 token from idp and now access into app2, my question is, how first tenant user can access to app2 resources? how app2 distinguish claim or role from user from another tenant?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Could you be more clear?

Answer (score 1):

You can share the resources among tenants by enabling the SaaS Application property.

1. Click on "Edit" link of service provider.
2. Enable the "SaaS Application" checkbox.

For more information, refer to [THIS LINK](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers)